# Mocking an API with Nock and SuperTest

Tags: request, mocha.js, nock

I have this very simple test for a GET, run via Mocha

```
import chai from 'chai'
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http'
import {should, expect} from 'chai'
import nock from 'nock'
import request from 'supertest'

    const url  = 'http://mysite-beta.com'
    const api = '/api/user'


    describe('/GET route', () => {
        it('it should GET the mocked response', (done) => {      
            nock(url)
            .get(api)
            .reply(200, {
              "status": 200,
              "message": "This is a mocked response"
            });

          request(url)
            .get(api)
            .end(function (err, res) {
              // ****** the next line gives an error ******
              expect(res.body.status).to.equal(200);
              expect(res.body.message).to.equal("This is a mocked response");
              done();
            });
        });
      });
```

But when I run it I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined`. res is undefined
Everything is setup e.g. npm packages etc

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. It is working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example using `nock` with `mocja` and `supertest`:

```
var nock = require('nock');
var request = require('supertest')("http://api.postcodes.io&quot;);
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe("Testing API with a mocked backend", function () {

  it("returns a successful mocked response", function (done) {
    
    //specify the url to be intercepted
    nock("http://api.postcodes.io&quot;)
      //define the method to be intercepted
      .get('/postcodes/')
      //respond with a OK and the specified JSON response
      .reply(200, {
        "status": 200,
        "message": "This is a mocked response"
      });
    
    //perform the request to the api which will now be intercepted by nock
    request
      .get('/postcodes/')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        //assert that the mocked response is returned
        expect(res.body.status).to.equal(200);
        expect(res.body.message).to.equal("This is a mocked response");
        done();
      });
  })
});
```